# How do you create a usb drive that can boot on both UEFI and Legacy computers? (Without 3rd party programs)

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10, usb-drive

I want to create a USB image that can boot on both UEFI and Legacy computers. I have accomplished this task with a MDT image by putting the boot files in a fat32 partition and the Deployment Share in a NTFS image.

Now i want to do this on a normal image. What i wonder is the following.

If the process for creating this image is the same as how you do it with a MDT image. What files do i need to put in the fat32 partition and what files do i need to put in the NTFS partition.

If the process is different for this image, How do you create it?

Answer (score 0):

Alright. I solved it by following this guide https://winaero.com/create-bootable-usb-for-windows-10-install-wim-larger-than-4gb/ .

The only manual step i had to do which wasnt written in the guide is to create the 2nd partition